# Clojure cats append nil behaviour

Tags: clojure, category-theory, monoids

I am using [`funcool/cats`](http://funcool.github.io/cats/latest/#monoid), append monoid with the following code :

```
(m/mappend (maybe/just [1 2 3])
             nil
             (maybe/just [4 5 6])
             (maybe/nothing)) ;;=> #<Just [1 2 3 4 5 6]>
```

What is the rationale for treating `nil` as maybe/nothing ?

Note : the version is `[funcool/cats "1.2.1"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [commit log](https://github.com/funcool/cats/commit/3a5bbf8d77aceb927ac3c75d3611fadeed27029d), it seems like it's

> just for *(sic)* avoid accidental null pointer exceptions

This is also documented here: http://funcool.github.io/cats/latest/#nil

> Given the fact that nil is both a value and a type, we have extended
>   the nil type to be equivalent to Maybe monad’s Nothing.